# How to navigate to another page on button click in vuetify?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, prestashop, vuetify.js

I am trying to navigate to another page after clicking a button in vuetify but unable to do it. After clicking the Next Page button it should navigate to newpage.

This is the url where the button is:

```
http://localhost:8080/viewer/?id_product=548
```

Here is my code:

**ProductDetailsCard.vue**

```
<v-btn @click="this.$router.push({path: '/newpage'})">Next Page</v-btn>
```

**router > index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import NewPage from '../components/NewPage.vue';

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.eventNames.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/newpage',
            name: 'newpage',
            component: NewPage
        }
    ]
})
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Vuetify button supports `to` attribute

```
<v-btn to="/newpage">Next Page</v-btn>
```

But you problem is in diffrent place, use component without quotes, as reference to component class, not string value.

```
component: NewPage
```

Comment: and what is current message after fixing quotes?

Comment: No message. Nothing happens after clicking the button.

Comment: Does /newpage url work if it's entered directly to browser?

Comment: no, /newpage url does not work if it's entered directly to browser.

Comment: So, that's where you need to start. Button itself is correct, your routing is broken, but I can't guess how.

Comment: When I click on the button, it shows error in console: `"TypeError: Cannot read property '$router' of null"`

Answer (score 0):

your route is named, so I recommend use it calling its name:

```
<v-btn @click="this.$router.push({name: '/newpage'})">Next Page</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make changes in **App.vue** and **index.js**:

for **App.vue**:  add these: `<Newpage/>`  and  `import Newpage from'@/components/Newpage'`

for **index.js**: `import Newpage from '../components/Newpage.vue'`and
`{ path: '/newpage', name: 'Newpage', component: Newpage }`

and finally use this `<v-btn to="/newpage">Next Page</v-btn>` where you want!

I hope these help you! :)